# How can we put more than one activity in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to put more than one activity in my main.java file but I don't know how to as I'm a newbie. I have inserted activity one but now I want to put activity two but unable to. Can you help me with it, the code until now on my main.java is:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, One.class));

        }
    });
}
```

I have already created another activity files named Two.class and two.xml. How will the code be for next activities?

Comment: You want to call different activities on different view clicks or something else?

Comment: please explain your requirement of placing 2 activitys in one class first.

Comment: pls check the docs http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: @vamshi yes I want to call different activities from the main page that is main.java. I will be having some 5-10 textview which will be forwarded to another pages of activity.

Comment: maybe a different button's `onClick` will start the other activity?

Comment: Similar to how you added One Activity, you can start your Two Activity in response to some other event. There is no restriction in pointing to multiple activities from one activity.

Comment: @gvmani I tried coding it similarly but it is showing me error with:

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState) {

and it is also showing error at     });

When I click Ctrl+1 it shows No Suggestions.

Comment: @Techno23 Could you provide the error details ?

Comment: @gvmani it is just saying No suggestions with a Red cross button on the side.

Comment: @Techno23 post the whole code, or since there are no error messages try a clean rebuild, sometimes eclipse takes you for a ride.

Comment: Each (actual) Activity needs its own class file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want two activity in a single calss use Fragments.

Fragments are mini activity in Android. They combine two or more than two activity in a single activity class

see following link for more detail

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I think it will help you